# Compactness of operator $T_K(f)(s) = \int_0^1 K(t,s) f(t)\,{\rm d}t.$

Tags: operator-theory, compactness

I am trying to solve this problem. Let $K:[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow C$ be continuous function and operator $T_k:C[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ defined as $T_K(f)(s) = \int_0^1 K(t,s) f(t){\rm d}t$, where $K(s,t)=\overline{K(t,s)}$. Is this operator compact?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? You might not know this since you seem relatively new, but on this forum its is expected of question askers to provide context in the form of some of the efforts or research they put in, even if it lead nowhere, as it lets the volunteers of this site make more adequate comments and answers by having a better chance at pinpointing the issues you had. This context can be failed or incomplete attempts, or it can simply be stating/naming results that you deem appropriate for the situation. For example here, do you know about the Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Comment: You can find a solution on chapter 7 of "Fundamentos de Análise Funcional" by Geraldo Botelho.